# dpkg-query show installed package only

Tags: debian, ubuntu, dpkg

I'm trying to list installed packages with custom format,

```
dpkg-query -f '${Package}###${Version}\n' -W '*'
```

But it also print those are removed.

Is there any way to filter them out? I'm trying to avoid doing a `grep -v '###$'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you drop the package name pattern, `dpkg-query` will only list installed or configured packages:

```
dpkg-query -f '${Package}###${Version}\n' -W
```

This gives the same result as your putative `grep`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `--showformat` option to list the installed package + version:

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\t${Version}\n' --show
```

Comment: This will show packages, which are remove but not installed (`rc`).